# Como fazer para o texto dentro do botão não seja inclinado?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Button</title>
    <style>
        .slanted {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 2px solid #9b9999;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00dd, #e03e3e);
            outline: none;
            color: #e4e1e1;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
            transform: skew(-40deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button class="slanted button1" type="button">Login</button>    

</body>
</html>
```

Eu estou criando um botão para um site que estou desenvolvendo, mas o problema é que quando eu inclino o botão 40 graus negativos no eixo x `transform: skew(-40deg)`, o texto dentro do botão é inclinado também já tentei diversas formas pro texto não inclinar junto, mas não adiantou! quem puder ajudar fico muito agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Basta acrescentar no style do **.example{}** **display:block;** e **transform: skew(40deg);**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Button</title>
    <style>
        .slanted {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 2px solid #9b9999;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00dd, #e03e3e);
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
            transform: skew(-40deg);
            
        }

        .exemplo {
            color: #e4e1e1;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;  
            display:block;
            transform: skew(40deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button class="slanted button1" type="button">
          <span class="exemplo">Login</span>
    </button>    

</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Tente dessa forma:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Button</title>
    <style>
        .slanted {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 2px solid #9b9999;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00dd, #e03e3e);
            outline: none;
            color: #e4e1e1;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
            transform: skew(-40deg);
        }

        .exemplo {
            transform: skew(40deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button class="slanted button1" type="button">
          <span class="exemplo">Login</span>
    </button>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não funcionou! já tinha tentando este método!

Comment: O problema tem a ver com o `display:inline` do `<span>`. Se trocar para `block` já funciona.

Comment: Isso mesmo funcionou, valeu amigo! sugiro que você coloque uma resposta para eu marcar como resolvida.

Answer (score -2):

Basta colocar o seu texto dentro de outro elemento, e aplicar uma regra diferente pra ele. Exemplo:

```
<button class="slanted button1" type="button">
     <span>Login</span>  
</button>
```

Aqui, eu coloco seu texto dentro de um `<span>`, e depois aplico a regra no `.css`:

```
.slanted > span {
  display:block;
  transform: skew(40deg) !important;
}
```

Como é um `<span>`, foi necessário inserir um `display:block` para alterar o valor padrão dele que é `inline`, e depois passo um `transform` com o valor inverso ao que é utilizado no botão, e coloco um `!important` para sobrepor a propriedade do botão no `<span>`, assim tendo o resultado que você espera.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!